# Is it possible to make a disaccharide from two fructose monomers? If so, what is its name?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates

Maltose is a disaccharide made from two molecules of glucose; and sucrose (table sugar) is made from glucose and fructose. Is it possible to combine two fructose molecules to make a disaccharide?

If so, what is that called? Or if not, what prevents the glycosidic bond from forming?

Comment: I don't really see the need to close this question.

Comment: @orthocresol it is not a homework question either. I am just a curious layman.  I looked up disaccharide charts, and not a single one had two fructoses listed.

Comment: I was curious how two fructoses would compare in sweetness to other disaccharides

Comment: This is not at all as trivial as it seems, and I certainly disagree with the close verdict of the community. I would recommend detaching the request for a comprehensive list of disaccharides from the question. There is a [fairly comprehensive table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaccharide#Common_disaccharides). I couldn't find anything more comprehensive. In general I do not doubt the existence of a fructose dimer, as there are fructooligosaccharides of the form $\ce{GF_{n}}$, and decomposition will probably yield some kind of di-fructofuranose... it's all hard to find though.

Comment: See for example Peter Forgo *et. al.*,  *Microchemical Journal* **2013,** *107*, 37-46. [DOI: 10.1016/j.microc.2012.06.017](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.microc.2012.06.017)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン yes, unfortunately, the wikipedia article had the most comprehensive list, and it seems to me, to be quite far from unabridged. Anyway, the question has been edited to remove that request.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン also, from more googling, I have learned that polysaccarides composed of fructose are called fructon; however, this is not precisely what I was looking for as it refers to a wide range of chemical structures.

Comment: I also disagree with closing this question. In my opinion, the question was even fine in its original scope. We could have had a community wiki answer, with columns, *e.g.*, common trivial name, monosaccharides, linkage, PIN, and reference to IUPAC (or similar) document, or published article (+ perhaps picture). Of course, the incentive for answerers would have been lower, but over time the table would probably be better-referenced and more comprehensive than on Wikipedia. Anyhow, I am voting to reopen this question as is.

Comment: Google fructofuranosyl fructofuranoside. Also fructofuranosyl fructofuranose. You will find some.

Answer (score 2):

in agave plants the typical sugars are fructans (fructose-polymers) like inulin, levan, agavin - with sometimes really complex structures comparable to starch. As starch breaks down into glucose, maltose, etc. you have also a need for break-down process e.g. in the tequila/mezcal industry which is usually a thermal hydrolisis (no enzymes like in beer). This hydrolisis is never complete so you have dimers and trimers (or higher) fructose-sugars, which are even metabolizable by yeast-strains. They are referred to as nistose or kestose (https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/1-Kestose#section=Top).
I hope this answer helps you to finally resolve your question - check out also user55119 coment.

Answer (score 0):

A molecule of two fructoses is called inulobiose or difructan (PubChem: 439552).
It occurs naturally in the fungus Aspergillus.
https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Inulobiose
see also
Matsuyama (1982) J Biochem 92(4):1325-8. doi:10.1093/oxfordjournals.jbchem.a134051.PMID:675724